# Calling function on new keyword

Tags: java, new-operator

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Date;

class basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = new Date().toString();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me in complete detail, how the line `new Date().toString();` gets executed by the JVM. I am not really interested in how `new` allocates a heap, but how can we use the `.toString()` operator on constructor `Date()`. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "but how can we use the .toString() operator on constructor Date()" you're calling `toString` on the instance returned after the _Date_ constructor is invoked not directly on the constructor.

Comment: Simple: `new Date()` creates a new Date. This is an expression, and a method call expression is `e.method(arg1, arg2, ...)`, where `e`, `arg1`, `arg2` must be an expression of the right type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Date().toString();` is interpreted by Java's compiler as `(new Date()).toString()`. Which is the same as `Date a = new Date(); a.toString();`

Comment: Java is so loosly typed that we can pass by not using () around `new Date()`. Because I come from C backround, where we do not get this much of freedom it becomes really confusing sometimes. Thank You for the answer.

Comment: I think you mean `weakly` typed language

Answer (score 4):

It'll be easier to understand if we split the code in a couple of lines and introduce local variables. This line:

```
String s = new Date().toString();
```

Is the same as:

```
Date d = new Date();
String s = d.toString();
```

You see now, we're calling the `toString()` method on an *instance* of the `Date` class, not on the constructor itself.

Comment: oof, 7 seconds before me. But with better formatting